# Reopen controversial question?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

The question: [Is it a good idea to make huge objects dynamic in C++?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/381594/131624) is closed as too broad for a reason I don't fully understand and, at the moment, can't support.

The question is about the ramifications of a design decision. Granted it has a few misconceptions baked into it but so do some of the best questions. I don't think an entire book is needed to properly answer this question.

Questions get closed for the wrong reason all the time. If that's what happened here fine but please lets at least make the real issues clear so the OP learns the right lesson. I'd add the comment myself but right now I've no idea.

Answer (score 4):

I agree the close reason given might be debatable. The question was originally so badly written I was not even sure I understood what the OP really meant. And for questions which make us play guessing games I typically vote to close as "unclear" or "too broad" .

Rereading the question in context with [amon's answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/381596), it got a more focussed interpretation. However (even after your honarable attempt to clean up the mess a bit), it is still so badly written I hesitate to revoke my close vote. And even if someone takes the time to improve the question to the degree it does not make us guess around what in the OP's code happens, I think it could still be closed as a duplicate of ["Is micro-optimisation important when coding?"](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/99445/is-micro-optimisation-important-when-coding).

So no, I don't think I am revoking my current close vote, at least not as long as the OP (or someone else) is not going to invest some time and improve the question to a higher quality standard.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'd dispute that duplicate on the basis that this isn't asking if micro-optimisation is important. It's asking if this particular practice is a micro-optimisation. Two things I'm now wondering about. Why does "guessing games" -> "too broad" and not "unclear what you're asking"? Most importantly, how is the OP going to invest time improving the question when no one has asked for what you need to revoke the close vote?

Comment: @candied_orange: you are correct, I typically vote as "unclear what you are asking" or "too broad" - in this case, I am actually not sure what I voted, I still think it fits both. And yes, I could have taken more time and comment on the question about all the reasons why I think it is not a good question - but my impression here is, I could invest such efforts better into questions where I see a higher chance of getting them saved.

Comment: ... and honestly: a sentence like *"I have an engine and if i want to use the d3d systems i always have to pass a pointer to any mesh renderer."* gives me not the impression the author is able or willing to write a good question (not saying I could not be wrong with this). But telling people that directly in the face could violate our code-of-conduct, so sometimes it is better to say nothing.